# Copy files from search tab in eclipse 3.4

Tags: eclipse, search, copy, paste

I just want to copy list of files displayed in eclipse search tab,
When i try using right click copy and paste into some folder it does not work.It actually copies the file location rather than the file itself

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do this. What you can do is:

1. Double click on the entry in the search tab
2. <kbd>F12</kbd> to switch to the editor
3. <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+W</kbd> to select the file in the navigator view
4. Drag the file from there to the place where you want it

Too tedious? Then open a command prompt or shell and use the file location there.

Comment: i would rather copy the file locations into a file and then write a java plug in .Anyway thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you need file locations then use [Eclipse search csv export](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-search-csv-export#.U13x7aaoJk-) plugin.

If want to copy the whole file(s) into a folder then refer @Aaron Digulla answer(Its applicable to single file). In case of multiple files. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all search results in search view. Right click on the selection. Choose `Show In > Package Explorer`. Drag file(s) to a folder in any file explorer.